# Advice on Article ID and its Comment ID Shown in HTML Hidden Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, django

I have a blog that I developed using **Django** which allows users to publish articles and each articles can get commented on.

I have **Article TABLE**. **Comment TABLE** that has an `article_id` column.

When displaying **articles** it goes along with an `<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="user_id" value="article_id">`. This value is extracted with **JavaScript (AJAX)** when a user comment on an article to have it saved in comment table appropriately.

*My Fear:*

Since the `hidden value` can get edited using **Developer Tools** or something, can't someone comment on article with value 1 and have it saved on article 1000 if the value is tampered with?

How do I deal with this?

Comment: You are true this can be done. But Note if anyone wants to genuinely comment he/she will never gonna do that.So you can neglect that problem.

Comment: You have a similar problem that someone can come along and post a load of total nonsense, ads, links to their online shop--anything really--through the commenting system. It's just one of those things that can happen if you have comments enabled. If you are particularly worried, let the authors of the articles moderate the comments, so they have to be OK'd to be published. That should also weed out the comments that appear to be relevant to other articles.

Comment: @ialarmedalien: You mean there is nothing one can do except moderating the comment? :(

Comment: I can guarantee to you that the number of people and bots posting links to porn, online shops, and other such spam will be at least a millionfold larger than people using dev tools (or even writing their own user agents!) to post comments on inappropriate articles.

Comment: If your only worry is that people can tamper with the form data, you can sign it using, for instance, <http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/>. That way, you sign the `article_id` and pass that value along with your form. In the form validation, you can check to see if the signed value is valid.

Comment: @Tiago: That is what I am looking for. Unfortunately, the link in your comment is broken. It returns `404 Not Found`

Comment: Sorry about that. The stackoverflow URL regexp seems to be wrong and including the extra `>` in it. Try now http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/ . If that's what you're looking for, I can write a proper answer with some code.

Comment: @Tiago: Thank you. Django even have it.

Comment: Have you considered storing article_id on request.session?
And agree with @Tiago that signing it will also work.

Comment: @Anzel: storing in the session is not ideal. Imagine the user opens, at the same time, two articles in two different tabs. Now, since the session is the same for the same user, it will contain only the article_id of the last request made. If the user comment on the first tab, the comment will be saved on the other article.

Comment: @Tiago, fair point. As your concerns being around users tampering the value, using session comes strict to my mind.
You may consider putting this constraint on your question so others understand as well